# cp: prevent error when source and destination are the same

Tags: cp, coreutils

Can you tell cp (GNU coreutils) to prevent reporting an error on:

```
$ echo 1 > foo
$ cp foo foo
```

Currently, this reports:

```
cp: 'foo' and 'foo' are the same file
```

That's very sensible, but it's not always necessarily going to be an error. Conceptually, if you are copying files from `$source` to `$dest`, if you are already in the `$dest` directory, then essentially the copy is already done by construction; so, *depending on context*, this should not necessarily be reported as an error. I can't find anything in the manual page for this. The `--update` option doesn't work although it sounded like it might.

Obviously, I can work around this is many ways, but I was wondering if cp could do this off the bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with GNU coreutils (as of coreutils 8.27). The documentation doesn't mention it, and the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/copy.c;h=965e8190db03a8a4ba665ea6d4e9d5f44055ae63;hb=ba16bdd89064a58d828d557827a473fc02b0d5ad#l1425) doesn't show any undocumented way. The test for same-file-ness only permits it when making hard links or in some cases where the files are symbolic links to the same destination.

Rsync allows it, so a simple solution would be to use `rsync` instead of `cp`.

Comment: Oh, rsync: that's a good shout. Thanks! Thanks for the link too :)